# Generate multiple sheets in one pdf file

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to generate a pdf from a Tableau workbook which has two sheets using the url method:
E.g: https://TableauServer/views/workbook/sheet1?:format=pdf&parameter=value

I am doing this in a program which will issue the url request to the url. The url works fine for one sheet. But the problem is how to generate one pdf file with both sheets in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you first put your two sheets into a single dashboard and then use the URL for the published dashboard (still using the *format=pdf* parameter), this should work just fine.

Comment: there is a reason i have to seperate the sheets.

Comment: Could you perhaps publish the two sheets individually still in your main project, and have them combined in a dashboard in a secondary project? If the combined PDF only needs to be accessed via your code, you can still direct human users to the separated sheets.

Answer (score 0):

We know it's possible because within the Tableau pages itself if you download a PDF it gives you several formatting options, including the option to put all the worksheets in a workbook into a single PDF.

I couldn't find any documentation on it though. What I ended up doing was looking at the network console in the browser (usually F12) when I downloaded the PDF from the browser by clicking the Download button. That showed me the URL end point and the JSON body the server expected in the request payload.

The endpoint URL wasn't too cryptic and ended with "commands/tabsrv/pdf-export-server". The challenge was to take the JSON in the request payload and find the right settings to get it into a single PDF.

This method is a more technical approach and requires very little coding skills; any language that has functions for http calls will work (I use python for it).

If you don't mind doing it outside a browser, tabcmd has lots of functionality to control PDF generation at the command line.

Comment: ok, I tried downloading the pdf and select multiple sheets. I can see pdf-export-server and see the Request Payload, which is a json file and looks like a request to the server. Question is how to pass this request to the server? I mean how can i use this Json file to get the pdf file from the server?

Comment: Play with the settings in the json. One of those will be specific to whether you want one sheet or all sheets. Using php or another language with an http library, create a json object with those values. Then send the json object as part of the request body. The request library will need a URL, and use the URL you found with the pdf-export-server. You can do this in javascript, python, php, or any other language with an http library.